# Issues while converting string to a number

Tags: python-3.x, string, list, jupyter-notebook, int

I'm trying to cast the string thus obtained to an integer, however I end up getting this strangely weird output, why is it so?[Code block:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gayre.png)

I'm working with Jupyter Notebooks(Python3)

Comment: Hi @Shubhankar ! Next time, please add the code into your post (and not as an image). It would be easier for us to copy it and help you out.

Comment: Sure, It's my first time using stack overflow. I'd keep that in mind while posting queries in the future. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have initialized the value for `string` earlier. You need to assign the output of the function to a variable in-order to print it. Otherwise you would get an error.

This code should work for you:

```py
def convert(lst):
    string=''
    for i in lst:
        string = string + str(i)
    return string

a=convert([1,2,3,4,5])
print(int(a))
```

Output:

```py
12345
```

Comment: @Shubhankar Do accept the answer if this has helped you!